# Which file contains function of core/session in magento?

Tags: email, session, magento

I need to customize other's code,

so I found they used

```
     Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyCustomBlockInfo();
```

in Order.php file for custom order email

so I can't find this function  `getMyCustomBlockInfo();`

Can anyone tell me where this function reside?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**example :**

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); //or
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');
```

the code must be in '**../app/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php**' file

**then**

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
```

the code must be in '**../app/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php**' file

---

because the class **Mage_Core_Model_Session**'s parent::parent is **Varien_Object**, then you can do all magic functions and you can **->getData()** to see the **Data** inside.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData();
```

on your problem when go call ->getData() you can see data : [my_custom_block_info]

you can set it with call

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyCustomBlockInfo('what');

Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyCustomBlockInfo();
// will return 'what'
```

Answer (score 1):

those are magic functions get() and set() and you are asking a session variable there that is set as

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyCustomBlockInfo();
```

somewhere in your code. If you use terminal you can easily find by making a following grep:

```
grep '>setMyCustomBlockInfo(' . -rsni
```

and it will list the files where your variable is set to session.